# Ember - accessing parent route's model from controller

Tags: ember.js, controller

I have two routes, let's call them /user and /user/actions. How do I access the user model from a UserActionsController method?

I've tried something like:

```
this.modelFor('user').get('id')
```

and

```
this.get('target').modelFor('user').get('id)
```

but in both cases it sais that 'modelFor' is undefined and not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in a controller you would use `needs` and then get it off the controller.

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs:['userActions'],
  blah: function(){
    var userActionsModel = this.get('controllers.userActions.model');
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dofedehi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have not given this enough thought, but can't you simply access

`App.User` ?

I might have misunderstood the question of course.