# In EmberJS built by EmberCLI, how to call methods on different controllers?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, requirejs, ember-cli

I'm building an app in Ember with EmberCLI.

In my top navigation (controllers/navigation/top.js) I have an action that is triggered on a button click. This action should open the left navigation (controllers/navigation/left.js).

My top navigation controller:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    toggleMenu: function() {
      // I need to call toggleProperty on the left navigation controller. 
      [leftNavigationController].toggleProperty('visible');
    }
  }
});
```

How to get another controllers instance to call a method like `toggleProperty`?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189086/ember-accessing-parent-routes-model-from-controller/24189949#24189949, but a slight difference, so I'll copy and paste and show the diff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in a controller you would use `needs` and then get the controller and call it

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs:['bar'],
  blah: function(){
    var barController = this.get('controllers.bar');
    barController.toggleProperty('visible');
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dofedehi/2/edit

Comment: Works great, thanks! Didn't find the other question, so may come in handy for others searching for this..

Comment: oh yeah, np, figuring out the right thing to search for is half the battle, and it was different enough for me to not close it as a duplicate.